# Redirecting port 80 requests to local web server with IPFW

Tags: redirect, freebsd, ipfw

I'm setting up a freebsd router and want certain IPs on my network to be forwarded to our local webserver if they make port 80 requests.
An example would be - banned user tries to surf the web, but all his requests are forwarded to the web page which notifies him that he is banned.
As I understand I can use IPFW for this and maybe NATD.

I would be grateful if someone could show me a good example on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to bother with natd you need kernel compiled with IPFIREWALL_FORWARD option. You can check your current kernel  issuing 'sysctl kern.conftxt | grep IPFIREWALL_FORWARD'. If this option is absent you need to rebuild your kernel (or stick to pf).

If you have such kernel you just need to add this rules:

```
ipfw add allow tcp from any to 192.168.0.0/24 via internal_if0
ipfw add fwd localhost,80 tcp from any to any 80 via internal_if0
```

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD now comes with 3 (sic!) different firewalls, `ipfw2` is just one of them, and two left are Darren Reed's `ipfilter` and OpenBSD's `PF`. Both of them has built-in NAT which supports port redirecting "from the box", see, for e. g., PF's [way](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html). So why not use them instead?